# Can't turn off text formatting

Tags: python, python-requests, slack-api

It seems to me that mrkdwn option isn't working as it should.

```
import requests

url = 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage'
data = {'text': '_a_', 'token': <some_token>, 'mrkdwn': 'false', 'channel': <some_channel>, 'as_user': 'false'}

requests.post(url, data=data)
```

This code posts letter 'a' in italic style rather than '_a_'...

Has anyone had this kind of problem?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try to escape the "_" like this: 'text': '\\_a\\_'

Comment: Tried it, it actually posts that exact string - '\\_a\\_'

Comment: Only escape at the beginning: \\_a_ of the whole sequence

Comment: @igrinis if you mean something like this data = {'text': '\\_a_', 'token': <some_token>, 'mrkdwn': 'false', 'channel': <some_channel>, 'as_user': 'false'}, it doesn't write in italic but the backslash is present in the output so it basically writes out the text '\\_a_'.

Comment: try two backlashes

Comment: @igrinis nope, doesn't work which kind of makes sense... :)

Comment: try posting 'text': '&#92;_a_'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned parameter `mrkdown` does not exist as parameter for [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#formatting), so this can not work (Please compare with official documentation).

But you can control markdown formatting for attachments with the parameter `mrkdwn_in`.

Example:

```
{
    "text": "I am a test message http://slack.com, *this will be bold*",
    "attachments": 
    [
        {
            "text": "this is the attachments. *bold text*",         
            "mrkdwn_in": ["text", "pretext"]
        }
    ]
}
```

[Live demo](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22I%20am%20a%20test%20message%20http%3A%2F%2Fslack.com%2C%20*this%20will%20be%20bold*%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%22this%20is%20the%20attachments.%20*not%20bold%20please*%22%2C%22mrkdwn_in%22%3A%5B%22text%22%2C%22pretext%22%5D%7D%5D%7D)

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. So there isn't any way of controlling formatting for regular chat messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try providing boolean value for 'mrkdwn', like this:

```
'mrkdwn': False
```

Comment: should be small `f` in false so `'mrkdwn': false`

Comment: That won't work because false doesn't exist in python, only False.

Comment: It does work when using boolean value in message builder, see here: https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22_a_%22%2C%22mrkdwn%22%3Afalse%7D

Comment: @YuriySavchenko yeah, I saw that, however it's not working with my python code. Thanks anyway...